# Why won't Firefox display table cell border-right or border-left?

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, opera, css-tables

I have a table with the borders set for all table cells. This is used for a calendar. The table cell for the current date contains a div that changes the background color of that table cell. However, it overrides (or covers up - I'm not sure) the right and bottom table cell borders when viewing in Firefox. It overrides the top and left table cell borders in Opera. It works fine in Chrome and Safari. It has not been tested in IE. How can I get all borders to show in Firefox and Opera? Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table class="calendar" frame="box" rules="none">
    <tr>
        <td></td>...//seven td's total
    </tr>
    <tr><td class="very_light_gray"><div class="calendar_day_wrap">Today</div></td>...</tr>
    .... // 5 or 6 table rows total
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
.calendar {
    position:inherit;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:99999;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.calendar tr {
    height:20%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.calendar td {
    border:1px solid #ccc !important;
    width:14%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.calendar_day_wrap {
    position:relative;    
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.very_light_gray {
    background-color:#F8F8F8 !important;
}
```

Comment: If I could see the code that changes the background color, my ability to answer would be greatly improved. Also, border-collaps:collapse; should be "collapse". Also, why do you have all that z-index stuff?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I fixed the code above, and added the css for the background color. The z-index stuff is there for various reasons, but I changed it do different values, deleted it, etc., just to see if it had an effect. It didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You set `rules="none"`, which explicitly turns off column and row borders.

Then you set `border-collapse:collapse`, which collapses cell borders with column/row borders.  For each border segment there is a list of which border declarations take priority, and "explicitly turned off" has the highest priority per spec.

You want to either use `border-collapse: separate` or not set `rules="none"`.  Chances are, you don't want `frame="box"` either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `rules` and `frame`. I didn't really need them. However, I still don't see all the borders in Firefox or Opera. I don't want `border-collapse: separate` because I don't want double borders.

Comment: Well, if you're doing collapsed borders, and want 1px borders, then your problem is that theoretically the border is centered on the boundary between the cells, with 0.5px in each cell.  In practice most monitors can't do that without ugly antialiasing, so I bet the UA is snapping the border to the pixel grid.  But that can put it in the space of an adjacent cell...  Does using 2px borders help at all?

Comment: Good insight. 2px borders on the td does show up on Firefox, but it is half as thick as the other borders, so it is still not ideal. Also, I don't want 2px borders. Is there another way I can fix this?

Comment: Hmm.  I guess the other thing that's going on is that you have an element that has 100% of the cell's content width/height, but in the collapsed border model cell borders "leak" into the cell.  So your element overlaps the border, and since it's relatively positioned is painted later, hence over the border.  So what you want is to get it to not overlap the border.  Does giving the cells 0.5px or 1px of padding help?

Answer (score 0):

What about this code which is working in Opera 12.0 and Firefox.

```
.calendar {
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid #ccc;}

.calendar tr {height:20%;}

.calendar tr:nth-child(1) td {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:20%;}

.calendar td {
    width:14%;
    vertical-align: top;}

.calendar_day_wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;}

.very_light_gray {
    background-color:#F8F8F8;}
```